# Open a fragment from another fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, fragment

I developed a fitness application therefore when the user click the button "beginner" in the fragment it should lead to a list of exercises. My second fragment (fragment 2) was working initially but as soon as I customized this fragment and added images etc. It stopped working and I can't find out what the error is.

This is for my teacher.

Here's the part when it says that there is an error:

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2,container,false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

This is my error code:

```
10-14 20:15:28.697 3565-3602/harsh.banthia.myofficialbwf E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf 10-14 20:15:28.698 3565-3602/harsh.banthia.myofficialbwf E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824 10-14 20:15:53.445 3565-3565/harsh.banthia.myofficialbwf E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: harsh.banthia.myofficialbwf, PID: 3565
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 451584012 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 149MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3948)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:677)
        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:109)
        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:105)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:71)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:67)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createButton(AppCompatViewInflater.java:187)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:110)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:189)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at harsh.banthia.myofficialbwf.Fragment2.onCreateView(Fragment2.java:20)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: `OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 451584012 byte allocation` due to  Drawable size

Comment: I've run into a similar situation while loading large PNGs as drawable resources. I seem to remember that storing the drawables in `raw` instead of `drawable` helped, but this might not be good advice.

Comment: your image on the fragment is too big. have a look here https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: (I've pointed this out already, so I have downvoted this time. Please note that the link to the discussion about begging is not intended as an encouragement to use the phrases within. We want you to _avoid_ those phrases, for the reasons given. Read all of it please).

Answer (score 0):

It is due to your images you added in `Fragment`. So for sake of your application refer to https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap for loading `bitmaps` or your `drawables` efficiently in your `application`.

Comment: Hey! This looks like a very good solution, but I have been trying to work it out for the past few days and didn't make any progress. Can you tell me where should I upload code (Fragment2, Main Activity, Fragment) to resolve this conflict. If you like, I can send you my code for fragment2 and MainActivity or anything else that you need. Thanks!

Comment: public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2,container,false);
        Button button4=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction fra =getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fra.replace(R.id.fragment_container,new Fragment3());
                fra.commit();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }